# Module configuration translation

Tags: 8, configuration

I cannot find any good examples on how to make a module configuration translatable. Could someone give me a starter example to build off with?

Comment: You should definitely read this tutorial: http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2014-may-26/drupal-8-multilingual-tidbits-16-configuration-translation-development . It's part of a series of tutorials for multilingual Drupal 8 development by the same author. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

In config there are only few field types that are translatable by default text, label and i think date_format(you can check the schema types to see which field types exactly are translatable by default). You can also make any value translatable by adding the `translatable: true` flag to the field. Now, copy your **config/install** directory into **config/install/language/LANGCODE** and edit each one of those config files and keep only the translatable fields..and translate those :)

If you want to provide translations for you module so `t()` function will pick them up, that is a bit strange in D8 compared to D7 but to put it simply you have to edit your module's info file and put in the following lines:

```
'interface translation project': yourprojectname
'interface translation server pattern': relativepathtotranslationsdirectory/%project-%version.%language.po
```

Comment: Shouldn't the translation folder be `config/install/language/LANGCODE` instead?

Comment: You are correct, I have updated my answer.